# How to do border hover on menu

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, menuitem

I need to do border hover on every section of my menu.
On first section it's ok, but when i hover other elements there's left border and menu looking bad.

I no need double border on each side(left, right), need 1 border-left, 1 border-right in normal state and in hover state.

**Example:** http://codepen.io/smithua/pen/vHJqp

**Example of hover i need:** http://yadi.sk/d/q2yfzwh76vwsS

Comment: Please explain in more detail, where and why you think it is going bad.

Comment: nothing is different there

Comment: looks ok to me..whats the issue?

Comment: look ones more, i was update my post

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of line 26 in your CSS and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

remove `border-left-width: 1;` from `.clt_nav_tab ul li a {` (line 26)

just noticed user1702965 already adviced to remove line 26 :)

Comment: it's not what i need. I need every sertion 1 border(top,right,bottom,left)

Answer (score 0):

It is because your border has not the same size in normal state and in hover state.

in the normal state, with your code:

```
border: 1px solid #E5E3E3;
border-left-width: 0;
```

you have the border (top, right, bottom, left) (1px, 1px, 1px, 0px).

But in hover state, with the code

```
border: 1px solid #f88307;
```

you have the border (top, right, bottom, left) (1px, 1px, 1px, 1px).
So it means in hover state, the total size of your menu is 1px larger. A trick to prevent it from growing as you enter in hover state, is to fix its size in both state. For exemple you can replace the line (in normal state):

```
border-left-width: 0;
```

by the line:

```
border-left: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
```

That way your menu will always have a 1px border on every sides.

Comment: replace in normal state?

Comment: Yes, where you have the line border-left-width: 0;

Answer (score 0):

Try border-left:0; in .clt_nav_tab ul li a:hover class

Comment: but i need orange border on the left

Answer (score 0):

Change Only the Border color at line 39.

Answer (score 0):

Adding border affect the `width` of `li` while hovering.

Instead try using

```
outline: 1px solid #f88307;
```